# захезанный - смысл, происхождение

Tags: смысл

Смысловая нагрузка и происхождение слова "захезанный"

Comment: Не с автоответчиком ли говорите?

Answer (score 1):

Я таких слов избегаю. Читайте сами
http://mat.slovaronline.com/%D0%A5/%D0%A5%D0%81/4897-HEZAT

Фасмер объясняет происхождение кашинским диалектом  хеза́ть - "испражняться", кашинск. (См.), слово из жаргона русск. бродячих торговцев и воровского арго . Из греч. χέζω – то же; 
http://www.slovopedia.com/22/213/1644635.html